# Meaning of "to stay in hospital" in a headline vs. "will remain hospitalized" in the lead

Tags: present-tense, future-tense, headlinese

First, in the present and then in the future. Why? it's from a newspaper

The title is in the present tense. I don't understand why:

> #### Taylor *to stay* in hospital
>
> The actress, Elizabeth Taylor, *will* remain hospitalised for another day or two following a brain seizure that put her back in the hospital shortly after she was discharged following brain surgery, a spokesman said yesterday.

Comment: When we say someone 'is to' do something, that means that it is planned (in the present) that they will do that (in the future). I am to go to London next week. You are to see the boss later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I say: I am to go to the cinema next week. It is right? The usual is to say: I am going to the cinema next week.

Comment: I think there is a weak sense of *having to* do something; of being *compelled to* do something. As you say, "I am going to the cinema next week" is what we usually say. "I am to go to the cinema next week" suggests that you feel it is your *duty* to go, or that you have been asked or even told to go. Although it's possible that Taylor has *chosen* to stay in hospital, it's likely that she *has to* stay. "You are to stay in your room" is an order.

Comment: Headlines (the titles of articles in newspapers) use a very distinctive style of writing as explained in @Laurel's link. Headlines are not how normal people talk.

Comment: @SarahT I've read this style of writing not only in the title. For example:

Boris Johnson Set To Spend Second Night In Intensive Care After (headline)

Boris Johnson is to spend a second night in intensive care but remains in “good spirits”, a spokesperson for Downing Street said on Tuesday evening...

Would it be possible to use the future tense in these examples?

Comment: @mike111, yes, the future tense works fine in these sentences (and actually sounds better to my ear!) "Boris Johnson Will Spend Second Night In Intensive Care." "Boris Johnson will spend a second night in intensive care but remains in 'good spirits'."

Comment: OK, thanks a lot